# Objective-C ¿ Como guardar en una variable el puntero a un metodo estatico?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Me interesaría guardar en una variable la dirección de un método estático para luego llamarla cuando interese como si fuera un punteros a funciones en C.

¿ Como se implementaría en Objective C ? 
¿ Funcionaria igual para métodos no estáticos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo debes crear un selector apuntando al método estático de la clase

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"NombreDeLaClase");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"nombreDelMetodo");
```

Luego para llamarlo sólo debes hacer un perform selector

```
[class performSelector:selector];
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si solucionó el problema por favor márcala como correcta. Saludos.